# Is there snow in Sochi in summer?

Tags: russia, sochi

Looking at the World Cup location - Sochi, the temperatures are hitting 30 degrees Celsius (or like 100 F).

I also know that there is a Sochi Ski resort. Does it work in the summer?

Basically what I'm asking is: can I go to the beach and swim in the sea, and later go up to the mountains to ski?

Comment: Explain the down vote?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. While it was not my downvote, Stack Exchange does expect you to demonstrate your initial research in the body of the question. For example, a simple web search should turn up information about the ski areas and their operation during the summer. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: By the way, 30C isn't even 90F. 100F is 38C.

Comment: But isn't the answer pretty obvious? Skiing requires snow. Snow doesn't exist at 30C. Unless perhaps there are some in the Arctic, ski resorts everywhere are only open in the winter.

Comment: @DavidRicherby There's some [year-round skiing](https://www.onthesnow.com/news/a/585186/summer-skiing-16-sweetest-summer-ski-resorts) where the climate supports it (often on glaciers), so it's not impossible, just not possible in most of the world. (Ok, there's also [Ski Dubai](https://www.theplaymania.com/skidubai) and other indoor facilities, but air conditioning the desert doesn't count.)

Answer (score 3):

Not much snow in the summer, no. Consider [Rosa Khutor Alpine Resort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Khutor_Alpine_Resort), 30 miles from the Black Sea and host of the 2014 Olympic Alpine Skiing events. As of this writing, it's 17˚C with 0cm snow height: "spring snow." If you view their [webcams](https://en.rosaski.com/camera/), you can see some snow is still present at the high elevations right now, but not that much, and none at all lower down. It [operates as a resort in the summer](https://en.rosaski.com/summer/) and the ski season usually starts sometime in December.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **no.** There is not much snow in Sochi in the summer for skiing. You will not find skiing in the summer season.

And *yes*, it is totally possible to swim in the Black Sea and go skiing later that same day. The ski lift is about 40-50 miles from the sea. I saw a man body surfing in -20 degree weather in the Sochi port. Anything is possible in Russia.

I have visited Sochi and the Black Sea, during a cold January and during ski season. We first stayed at the beach one night. The next day we took a taxi to the mountains, and we went up the ski lift and stayed at the [Korporativnyy Tsentr hotel](http://sbcc.ru/) in the Upper Town part of Gorky Gorod resort (which I highly recommend for you to check out). I think we were the only people who were not skiing there?? Gorky Gorod was specifically built by European investors for the Sochi Olympics, and is made for tourists. And in particular, ski tourists. Many Russians enjoy skiing. Gorky Gorod has a ski lift in the "Upper Town" section, and different slopes levels for your abilities.

The Black Sea is a [1-2 hour taxi ride](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Hotel+Mercure+Sochi+Centre,+Ulitsa+Ordzhonikidze,+11%D0%B0,+Sochi,+Krasnodarskiy+kray,+Russia,+354000/Gorky+Gorod+Resort,+Estonskaya+Ulitsa,+%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8,+Krasnodar+Krai,+Russia/@43.5560842,39.7155767,10z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x40f5c9805b9c6a25:0x25a130dd91322cad!2m2!1d39.7244519!2d43.5773072!1m5!1m1!1s0x40f675b837e66c69:0x97eb53faafba953d!2m2!1d40.266975!2d43.6833644!3e0?shorturl=1) away from Gorky Gorod. It took our taxi two hours in the snow to get there.

The [official Russian Gorky Gorod website](https://gorkygorod.ru/en/resort_introduction) has good information related to your question. It seems that the ski season is December to May.

> ### Winter
>
> In consequence of special arrangement of mountains, our resort
>   has the longest ski season - from December to May. In winter we offer
>   30 km of slopes of different difficulty levels, illuminate slopes for
>   night skiing and slopes with artificial snowing. Also we have 11
>   gondola and chair lifts with through-put 2400 people per hour (the
>   largest capacity in our country).
>
> The resort run skiing schools, skiing mini club and ski accessories
>   hires.
>
> We pay close attention to security: we have the most skilled personnel
>   of the search and rescue service, start to prepare and test our cable
>   lifts in June.
>
> Ski slopes of different difficulty levels from green to black (total
>   length – 30 km from + 2300 to + 960 meters) Illuminate slopes (3,1 km,
>   evening skiing from +1500 to + 960 meters) Slopes with artificial
>   snowing (4,9 km from + 1500 м to + 960 meters, 70 snow production
>   cannon) Cable lifts (11 gondola and chair lifts with through-put 2400
>   people per hour) Optional services: 3 skiing schools, 1 skiing mini
>   club, 5 ski accessories hire

If you decide to visit during summer (June) they offer extreme mountain biking, rafting and even yoga!

> ### Summer
>
> We offer mountains activities both in winter and summer. For example,
>   our resort has the only complex of slopes for downhill mountain biking
>   in Krasnaya Polyana - Gorky Bike Park. We have wooden and dirt pump
>   tracks, wooden skill park to set up mountain bike skills.
>
> Also we offer hiking roots of different difficulty levels and
>   sightseeing ascension by cable lifts to + 2300 m above sea level.
>
> The whole family can visit Adventure Park in altitude +1500 m above
>   sea level with separate child route. Among other activities there are
>   quad biking, rafting and yoga in mountains/
>
> You can use the bicycle, scooters and segway rental services or
>   services of roller school.
>
> We are a part of the group of companies, which has infrastructure in
>   Imereti lowland. This fact gives us an opportunity to organize for our
>   guests the rest in mountains and on the seacoast. In summer season we
>   provide shuttles to the private beach several times a day.
>
> Gorki Bike Park (downhill routes at height +1000 meters) Wooden and
>   dirt pump tracks, wooden skill park (to set up mountain bike skills)
>   Hiking roots of different difficulty levels (from +2300 to +960 meters
>   above sea level) Sightseeing ascension by cable lifts (to +2300 meters
>   above sea level) Adventure Park in altitude +1500 meters above sea
>   level (with child route) Other activities: quad biking, rafting, yoga
>   in mountains Optional services: city and mountain bike hire, scooter
>   and segway hire, roller school Own beach on the seacoast (with
>   transfer service)

If you ever do go to Sochi for skiing, I highly recommend you stay in the "upper town" section of the resort. It is closest to the ski lift and will save you extra hassle of getting up to the lift. Go in winter and they have Alice in Wonderland theme everywhere.

> ### Upper Town (Gorky Gorod Russia)
>
> (+960 m) Upper Town at a height of +960 m is more suitable
>   for calm and private rest. Its architecture is more aristocratic and
>   resembles resort towns in Italy, Spain or South France.
>
> Here you can find hotels with wide territory, townhouses and chalets.
>   They are Rixos Krasnaya Polyana Sochi, Gorky Hotel (ex. Solis Sochi
>   Hotel), Gorky Hotel & Suites (ex. Solis Sochi Suites), Dolina 960,
>   Gorki Panorama, Gorki Art, Gorki Grand, Apartments Gorki Gorod +960
>   with a total capacity of 1070 rooms.
>
> Hotels have their own exits in the skiing area and on the main square
>   the cable lift station is located. Upper Town offers restaurants, bars
>   and cafes, places for running sporting and cultural events.
>
> Rixos Krasnaya Polyana Sochi – 114 rooms Gorky Hotel (ex. Solis Sochi
>   Hotel) – 120 rooms Gorky Hotel & Suites (ex. Solis Sochi Suites) – 52
>   rooms Dolina 960  – 48 rooms Gorki Panorama – 302 rooms Gorki Art –
>   166 rooms Gorki Grand – 194 rooms Apartments Gorki Gorod +960 – 74
>   rooms Corporate Centre Sberbank – 47 rooms